# How to use pytesseract in replit?

Tags: python

I want to **convert image to text** using pytesseract on Replit platform but how will I **import tesseract.exe** on repl? Can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

I'm not sure if your talking about Linux however as you did not specify that.

IF you are talking about Linux you should run install-pkg tesseract-ocr in the console and then pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "tesseract". Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).